Tensorflow: multiples modelos usando capa compartida
Recientemente estudiando Tensorflow encontré que es posible tener múltiples entradas (y salidas) usando capas compartidas como Add, Substract o Concatenate.
Si tengo dos modelos m_1 y m_2 previamente entrenados, ¿se pueden unir mediante una capa compartida definida en la biblioteca para usarlos en otras capas internas de un tercer modelo nuevo?
Se entrenaron dos modelos diferentes usando Tensorflow. Sus salidas están separadas, pero debo encontrar la forma de pasarlas a otra capa en común.

Sí, lo puedes hacer con concatenate. Deberías cargar el modelo, juntar las salidas de m1 y m2, y seguir con la estructura del modelo. Yo ocupo bastante concatenate, pero dentro de la estructura de un mismo modelo (así que no tengo un ejemplo para añadir como respuesta), pero es posible sin problema alguno
